# vscode перестал видеть импорты js, ts, tsx

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, модули

Клонировал репо нового проекта, запустил в vscode, в нем он перестал видеть импорты. Открыл старый проект и в нем тоже появились ошибки в импортах :Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307). В абсолютно всех импортах[image: 1]

Путь теперь почему-то идет из диска C:

[image: 2]

В tsconfig:

[image: 3]

Comment: Не приводите код картинкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я запускал файлы из wsl ubuntu в vscode. Пофиксил баг этим плагином: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl

Answer (score 0):

попробуй в консоли написать npm install, предварительно перейдя в каталог с проектом через терминал в VSCode, проверь  зависимости  в package.json